# Calling out cookie value (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

I have a cookie that I set from `domain A` and trying to retrieve the value at `domain B` . Here is how I set my cookie from `domain A`.

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'userId',
    'value'  => $_SESSION['user']->id,
    'expire' => time() + 3600,
    'domain' => 'example.com',
    'path'   => '/',
    'prefix' => 'mycookie_',
    'secure' => FALSE,
);

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

So when I do `var_dump($this->input->cookie('mycookie_userId'));` it will return me the value like this `string(2) "78"`

From `domain B` I tried to print out the value `var_dump(get_cookie('mycookie_userId'));` but it return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. When setting the domain name I set it like `example.com` then I changed it to `.example.com` adding the **dot** in front then it working fine now.